# How can I make the button next/previous to appear outside of the scroller, I use jQuery thumbnail scroller

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

If there was a way to have the next and previous buttons to appear outside of the scroller frame, I use [jQuery thumbnail scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-thumbnail-scroller/) by manos.malihu.gr.
I try in CSS, to make the class of the buttons important or visible, but no success.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the default buttons and create your own.

The file jquery.thumbnailScroller.js has these 2 lines

```
var $scrollerNextButton=$this.children(".jTscrollerNextButton");
var $scrollerPrevButton=$this.children(".jTscrollerPrevButton");
```

I don't know anything about the scroller but you can try to edit these lines to make it use your own buttons.

Comment: Thanks, maybe this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

it worked with flex slider . i hope it helps your cause.

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next { right: 0 !important; margin-right: -30px; 
   opacity: 1 !important; }

.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev { left: 0 !important; opacity: 1 !important; 
   margin-left: -30px; }

.flexslider { width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; }
```